# Save and retrieve a dictionary object from file

Tags: powershell

I have created a dictionary, populated that dictionary. Also saved the contents of the dictionary to a file.

```
$PasswordDictionary = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,string]'
$PasswordDictionary["abc"] = "xyz"
$PasswordDictionary["pqr"] = "efg"
$PasswordDictionary | out-string | set-content "C:\Passwords\Passwords.txt"
```

Password.txt looks like this

```
Key     Value                                                                                                                                                                                 
---     -----                                                                                                                                                                                 
abc     xyz
pqr     efg
```

Now i want to create another dictionary object and populate that dictionary with this file's contents. Not finding a suitable way to do this. When i try to read the contents from the file, its reading it as array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to serialize the data before saving it. You could convert it to Json for example:

```
$PasswordDictionary.GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Passwords\Passwords.txt"
```

Would give you the following file content:

```
[
    {
        "Key":  "abc",
        "Value":  "xyz"
    },
    {
        "Key":  "pqr",
        "Value":  "efg"
    }
]
```

You can read it back into Powershell using the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet:

```
$restored = (Get-Content "C:\Passwords\Passwords.txt" | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

In this case you don't get a dictionary back, but an object array. You can still iterate like below:

```
$restored | ForEach-Object { "{0} - {1}" -f $_.key, $_.value }
abc - xyz
pqr - efg
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use hashtables with json. They work similar to dictionaries.

To save the json:

```
$PasswordDictionary = @{}
$PasswordDictionary["abc"] = "xyzz"
$PasswordDictionary["pqr"] = "efg"
$PasswordDictionary | ConvertTo-Json |  set-content "C:\Passwords\Passwords.txt"
```

Reading the data back into a hashtable:

```
$hashtable = @{}
$json = Get-Content "C:\Passwords\Passwords.txt" | Out-String
(ConvertFrom-Json $json).psobject.properties | Foreach { $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```

Getting a value from the hashtable will work similar to the dictionary

```
$hashtable["abc"]
xyzz
```